# How to mass import FLVs into Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Right now importing an FLV and embedding it in the timeline of a movieclip is a pretty slow process as it involves going through the wizard.  Is there an efficient way to do a mass import of FLVs and have each of the FLV be embedded in individual movieclip?

(NOTE: I understand the implication of embedded FLV and other options but let's assume embedded FLV is the only option here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I have found no way to automate that FLV import wizard (wtf Adobe??).

Since there is no AppleScript support in Flash (it has JSFL after all) the furthest I got was with Apple's UI Scripting but this I abandoned because it was impossible to account for the various times different videos would take to import.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, given that you want to import them. Something like this is possible using JSFL.

JSFL a javascript extension system that works in the flash authoring environment.
There are methods for adding items to both the timeline and into the library.

Here are [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_ExtendingFlash/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fe8.html), look at the library.addnewitem and document.additem methods.

This should do the trick

Comment: I don't think it will work.  Regular items can be imported straight onto the stage or into a movieclip but importing FLV triggers a wizard.

Comment: In that case... I would look at an automation application like AutoIt.